# Jenkins build based on selected branch from git

Tags: git, jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, branch

I have created a jenkins file that will list the branches from the git repository. It will be shown in choice. What is need to do is that, I must build the selected branch only.
I have used the following code to list the branches and save it in branch.txt file

```
stages {
stage('getbranches') {
        steps {
            git credentialsId: 'All', url: 'https://myrepo@bitbucket.org/professional/project.git'
            sh '>branch.txt'
            sh 'git branch -r | awk \'{print $1}\' ORS=\'\\n\' >>branch.txt'

        }
    }
}
```

in the next stage I select the branch with this code

```
stage('Select a branch') {
        steps{
            script{
            listBranches = readFile 'branch.txt'
            echo "please click on the link here to chose the branch to build"
            BRANCH_NAME = input message: 'Please choose the branch to build ', ok: 'Select',
            parameters: [choice(name: 'BRANCH_NAME', choices: "${listBranches}", description: 'Branch to build?')]

         }
     }
}
```

Now how do I build only the chosen branch.

What I tried is to checkout using the below codes and simply add the build stage.

```
stage ('checkout a branch') {
        steps {
         echo "checking out branch ${BRANCH_NAME}"
            git credentialsId: 'All', url: 'https://myrepo@bitbucket.org/professional/project.git'
            sh 'git checkout "${BRANCH_NAME}"'

        }
    }
```

1. Will just checking out a branch and building it builds that branch
   alone?
2. or will that build the master branch rather that the chosen
   branch.

If yes, then how can I build the chosen branch alone?

- Also, everytime when I run the jenkins pipeline, It must not use the
  old files that was cloned during last build.

Answer (score 0):

Not got your problem properly, please find the below which I figured out for your case.

I would say rather use GIT Web-hooks to implement your case, as in web-hooks it will trigger the branch in which you will do any changes (in Jenkins create a multi-branch pipeline, so that it will create a job for each of your branches)

Please follow the below:-

1. [How to create Multibranch pipeline in jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/)
2. [How to add webhooks](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline)

In this only the branch in which you will make changes, the build will be triggered for that only.